# Limited project access and visibility on Team Foundation Server

Tags: tfs

I have two different  project in my TFS. They are in the same collection. Can I setup Team Foundation Server for users only see and work on one project which I assign to them? I want them to work only one project without being able to see the other one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Team Foundation Server Permissions - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252587%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

> Project-Level Permissions
>
> Project-level permissions are specific to a single project's users and
>   groups. You can set these permissions in Team Foundation Server by
>   right-clicking the project in Team Explorer and clicking Security.
>   Additionally, you can set these permissions by using the TFSSecurity
>   command-line utility.

Comment: Hi Ahmet,Actually I did some settings in Team Explorer Security menu.But I cant add a user to a group